# Mac Quick Preview change file datetime in NFS shares

Tags: macos, quicklook, nfs

In macOS Monterey, when I quick look files located on NFS shares, the modify date/time has been changed.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: Can you post some examples?  What are you seeing and what do you expect the “correct” values to be?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `noatime` and `nodiratime` on the client. or

You can add the option when connecting in Finder: `nfs://vers=4,noatime,nodiratime,myhost.mydomain.com/nfs/share`,

or you can add them to `/etc/nfs.conf`:

`nfs.client.mount.options = vers=4,noatime,nodiratime,...`

See more info here: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-tuning-nfs-server-client-performance/

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't work. Opening the file will not modify the date modified but accessing it through Quicklook on Finder still modifies the date